# NSLog error: Can't find 'NXConstantString'?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gcc, nslog, gnustep

I finally got GNUstep working (on windows), and it compiles and runs fine. However, whenever I try to use NSLog, I get the following error:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers \
> -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
hello.m: In function 'main':
hello.m:4:5: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NXConstantString'
```

My source code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void) {
    NSLog(@"hello world");
}
```

Comment: After some more experimenting, it seems that I get this error whenever I have a @ before my string, not just when I use NSLog.

Comment: Not having an `@` before your string would make it a plain C string, which is the wrong type to use for `NSLog`'s format string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is -

```
NSLog(@"hello world");
```

not

```
 NSlog(@"hello world");  // 'l' should be upper case in NSLog
```

Try this -

```
gcc -o hello hello.m -I /usr/lib/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers \
-L /usr/lib/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/ -lgnustep-base \
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

[How to compile objective c programs using gcc](https://web.archive.org/web/20120816003625/http://blog.lyxite.com:80/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$gcc -o hello hello.m -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

***Note***

```
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

without this command it consider constant string objects  as a class type `NXConstantString`.

---

To run:

```
$./hello.m or whatever your objective-c code file name.
```

Comment: This worked for me after i added `-I/usr/include/GNUstep`

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple just put a space between `-lgnustep-base` and `-fconstant-class=NSConstantString`

Wrong way: `-lgnustep-base-fconstant-class=NSConstantString`

Right way: `-lgnustep-base -fconstant-class=NSConstantString`